# How to delete remote removed files using wget

Tags: linux, synchronization, wget

We are using recursive downloading of images from our server:

```
wget --no-parent -r -m --user=user --password=password http://........
```

We want to create scheduled job for total sync, but how can we remove images which were removed from server and aren't available any more?

Answer (score 0):

you can try the --content-on-error argument. 
 According to [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-Content-On-Error) manual, it will force wget to skip status error codes